# Newton - CG Optimization in python, problems with Jacobian

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to make Newton - CG Optimization in python. My function is f(x,y) =(1-x)^2 + 2(y-x^2)^2. Initial points: x = 3, y = 2. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

def f(params): #definite function
    x, y = params #amount of params 
    return (1 - x) ** 2 + 2 * (y - x ** 2) ** 2

def jacobian(params): #definite function
    x, y = params #amount of params
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    der[0] = -8 * x * (-x ** 2 + y) + 2 * x - 2 #derivative by x
    der[1] = -4 * x ** 2 + 4 * y #derivative by y
    return der

initial_guess = [3, 2] #initial points
result = minimize(f, initial_guess, jac = jacobian, method = 'Newton-CG')
```

I got an error `"IndexError: too many indices for array"`.

As I made Nelder - mead optimization, BFGS and they work. So, problem is with Jacobian matrix. I feel somewhere in `def jacobian` is a mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `der = np.zeros_like(params)`? Since `x` is a scalar?

Comment: Oh, yes. I see it works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rinkert I'm newbie on the stack overflow how can "like" your comment, to increase your rating or else on this forum as you really help me

Comment: There is a small arrow on the left of a comment, which you can press to upvote, but upvoting comments does not influence reputation. You can upvote and accept an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is indeed in the jacobian function, you are defining `der` as zeros taking the size of `x`, which is a scalar. Instead use `params`:

```
def jacobian(params): #definite function
    x, y = params #amount of params
    der = np.zeros_like(params)
    der[0] = -8 * x * (-x ** 2 + y) + 2 * x - 2 #derivative by x
    der[1] = -4 * x ** 2 + 4 * y #derivative by y
    return der
```